# Creating a Java project that uses myBatis and Sybase Database

Tags: java, sybase, mybatis, ibatis

Could someone please show me where to go for some decent tutorials for setting up ibatis using a sybase database.

There seems to be very little information out there on this and most of it uses mysql which is no good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle/Sun has a web page on the connection info you'll need at [Sybase JConnect Driver Configuration](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-3497/agqkg?l=ja&a=view). You'll use the same IBatis property names for any db. You can get the JDBC driver, if you don't have it already, at [Sybase](http://www.sybase.com/products/allproductsa-z/softwaredeveloperkit/jconnect). Once you get the connection set up then most of the tutorials should apply to any db. Primary key generation will probably be the most db specific issue to resolve.